# How Do I Test For More Than One Letter In A Loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, arguments

My Assignments Instructions Are Below

Use the System.out.println() method to tell the student to try again if they enter anything other than one letter for a grade.

Here is the code I'm using

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyGradeLoops {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {

        System.out.println("Please enter Your Class Grades");
        String A;
        char B;
        A = in.next();
        System.out.println("Thank You");
        if (**TRYING TO TEST FOR MORE THAN ONE LETTER**) {
            System.out.println("Only One Letter At A Time");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Keep Up The Good Work")
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyGradeLoops {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter Your Class Grades");
        String A;
        char B;
        A = in.next();
        System.out.println("Thank You");
        if (A.length() != 1) {
            System.out.println("Only One Letter At A Time");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Keep Up The Good Work");
}
}
```